# Fastlane error Could not receive the latest API key from App Store Connect, this might be a server issue

Tags: ios, fastlane, continuous-delivery

I'm getting a new Fastlane error after the command below the line:

```
bundle exec fastlane beta --verbose
```

And here is the error:

`Could not receive the latest API key from App Store Connect, this might be a server issue`.

I couldn't find any solution yet.

Best

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Solution

Use the command below to recreate session for Fastlane:

```
fastlane spaceauth
```

it'll send **2 Factor authentication** code to your registered device. Then you'll get the message:

```
Successfully logged in to App Store Connect
```

then it'll request you to:

```
pass the following via the **FASTLANE_SESSION** environment variable:

...some long terminal command and it's Example...
```

use the giving "Example" to pass the environment variable for Fastlane.

That's all.

I hope it'll help someone else in our universe.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use the same command with `sudo`.

Comment: Hi Yulia, this issue is already solved, unfortunately it's not about the sudo, this is more related with the 2 Factor authentication actually, please read the approved answer.

Answer (score 1):

Using "App Store Connect API" is over `spaceauth`.

Fastlane support App Store Connect API, and it has some benefits.
https://docs.fastlane.tools/app-store-connect-api/

You can create "App Store Connect API Key" in App Store Connect, and use it like below:

```
lane :release do
  api_key = app_store_connect_api_key(
    key_id: "D383SF739",
    issuer_id: "6053b7fe-68a8-4acb-89be-165aa6465141",
    key_filepath: "./AuthKey_D383SF739.p8",
    duration: 1200, # optional (maximum 1200)
    in_house: false, # optional but may be required if using match/sigh
  )

  pilot(api_key: api_key)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I got this issue when the AppStore console was under scheduled maintenance, no workaround required, check if you're able to access the AppStore console and if not then you probably have to wait